# Raspberry pi : apt-get update failes

Tags: raspbian, apt

I was following a tutorial and as dumb as it sounds I was ended up with editing sources.list file and adding new gpg key. now when i'm updating the apt-get i'm getting this error. Any help to get me out of this is highly appreciated.  Thanks

```
    Get:3 http://103.1.138.146/archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf Packages [143 kB]
Err:3 http://103.1.138.146/archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf Packages    
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:143052 [weak]
   - SHA256:f514a58006cec7fbbd43632402adb8dd532f1fa91572145425bb866d111bab97
   - SHA1:99e3c57149bc71c2f98651195880ac447aeca15b [weak]
   - MD5Sum:3c9ae8a120525bdbe6feba537c7e5826 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:5df39a393e9ffe012f7aa150b8a7035471954b5b3f433284643b72531e684ad9
   - SHA1:6c5dc4a721c4ba274cd726e7adf44fd43c83ebad [weak]
   - MD5Sum:59e2e01f65275244970812966d11bce8 [weak]
   - Filesize:142114 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 12:00:36 +0000
  Release file created at: Mon, 12 Mar 2018 13:45:42 +0000
Fetched 167 kB in 2s (75.6 kB/s)    

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list 
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

Following is the result when I manually download the Packages.gz file using wget

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74421/discussion-on-question-by-sudheera-raspberry-pi-apt-get-update-failes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference of others having the same problem. Any changes I did to the sources.list file did not worked. It' seems like the dns resolution of archive.raspberrypi.org redirected to some ip(103.1.138.146) which isn't getting the file with the expected hashsum. So I tried to update the apt offline. Using `apt-offline` utility I managed to update my rasp pi offline. (refer to [1] for steps)

After that `apt-get update` ran without an issue.

[1] https://www.maketecheasier.com/update-upgrade-ubuntu-without-internet-connection/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

then try again:

```
sudo apt-get update
```